# How to look only at entire words with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am writing personal information filter. When it encounters VALID phone or email replaces it with "[PRIVATE]";

Valid phone is  for example '0123 45678' and  '00123 45678' is invalid, but i get 0[PRIVATE] for the second one after the filtering. How do i look only at entire words using regex and `\bword\b` is totally not working properly.

Comment: Show your code, please!

Comment: @devnull: I just got my crystal ball back from the cleaners. I think I can take a shot at this :)

Comment: how `'0123 45678'` is valid but `'00123 45678'` is not?

Comment: @njzk2 It seems that the number should match `\d{4}\s\d{5}`

Comment: Note that matching ANY valid email or phone number will be nigh on impossible, since the regex to match email addresses is, well, [complicated](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm betting that you forgot to use raw strings:

```
re.search("\bword\b")
```

finds a string that starts with a backspace character, then `word`, then another backspace character.

```
re.search(r"\bword\b")
```

finds an entire `word`.

Comment: Yes, figured that you could _see_ the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This one will work:

```
re.search(r"([\d]+([\s]+)?[\d]+)")
```